# Turtle Variable export besides the export-world command?

Tags: netlogo

So the "export-world" command in Netlogo will export essentially everything from the model, but is there a more simplified version?  What I'm really after is just the values of all variables, both built-in and user-defined, of my turtles.

Less to parse through in the end.

Answer (score 2):

This might seem surprising, but I think that the closest thing that you'll find to what you're requesting is [`nw:save-graphml`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#nw:save-graphml) from the `nw` extension. The [GraphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/) format is based on XML and should be easyish to parse.

It doesn't matter if your turtles are connected by links or not. Unconnected turtles will still be saved by `nw:save-graphml`, with all their attributes.